# Why nginx+django+gunicorn are not serving static files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I've just tried a lot of things. Hope you guys can help me to resolve this.

I have a tipical problem serving static files for my django 1.5 project. I am trying to get a css file, per example, and it throws 404.

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    server_name t1.bpt.local www.t1.bpt.local;
    root /srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/t1.bpt.local-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/t1.bpt.local-access.log combined;

    ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1/bikepolo_tournament/assets;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 10;
        proxy_read_timeout 10;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8100;
    }
}
```

My supervisor conf file:

```
[program:bikepolo_tournament_t1]
directory=/srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1
command=/srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1/deploy/start_gunicorn_t1.sh
autostart=true
user=tom
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s-error.log
```

The supervisor command file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

APP_NAME="bikepolo_tournament"
PROJ_NAME="bikepolo_tournament"
DIR_SUFFIX="-t1"

VENV_PROJECTS="/srv/sites"
VENV_DIR="/home/tom/venvs/bikepolo-tournament"
GUN_CONF_MODULE="deploy/gunicorn.conf.py"

PROJ_HOME=$VENV_PROJECTS/$PROJ_NAME$DIR_SUFFIX
WSGI_MODULE=$APP_NAME.wsgi

source $VENV_DIR/bin/activate

cd $PROJ_HOME
exec gunicorn -c $GUN_CONF_MODULE $WSGI_MODULE:application
```

gunicorn.conf.py:

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import sys


GB_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(GB_BASE_DIR, 'bikepolo_tournament'))

from settings import get_run_mode


_run_mode = get_run_mode() # getting 'prod', 'test' or 'dev'

if _run_mode == 'prod':
    _bind_port = '8101'
    _number_workers = 1 + multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    _log_filename = 'gunicorn_www-error.log'
elif _run_mode == 'test' or _run_mode == 'dev':
    _bind_port = '8100'
    _number_workers = 1
    _log_filename = 'gunicorn_t1-error.log'
else:
    raise ValueError('Unexpected run mode: %s' % _run_mode)

debug = True

bind = '127.0.0.1:%s' % _bind_port

backlog = 1024
workers = _number_workers
```

My relevant part of django settings:

```
here = lambda *x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x)
PROJECT_ROOT = here("..")
root = lambda *x: os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x)
STATIC_ROOT = root('static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If I don't forget anything, those are my settings that are giving me an EPIC headache...

So, what Am I doing wrong? I am forgetting something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you ran `python manage.py collectstatic`? What does `ls -lt /srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1/bikepolo_tournament/assets` show?

Comment: `# ls -lt /srv/sites/bikepolo_tournament-t1/bikepolo_tournament/assets

total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 tom tom 4096 may 16 19:17 img
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 4096 may 16 19:17 css
drwxr-xr-x 3 tom tom 4096 may 16 19:17 js`

Comment: and I've ran collectstatic a lot of times..

Comment: I FOUND THE ANSWER!
in nginx config, alias in location /static/ MUST HAVE a trailing slash!